# How can I remove an extension for a VS Code profile?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have to switch between many projects in VS Code and up till now have been disabling/enabling extensions for specific workspaces. I now want to give code profiles a chance:

> Visual Studio Code has hundreds of settings, thousands of extensions, and innumerable ways to adjust the UI layout to customize the editor. VS Code Profiles let you create sets of customizations and quickly switch between them or share them with others.

My difficulty is with editing a profile once it is set up and has become less optimal (not sure how this happens really). Say I find that there is a Python Linting extension that now shows in a workspace that is a TypeScript profile. How can I remove that extension from the profile without removing it for other workspaces with the Python profile?

[The docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_edit-a-profile) simply say that a profile tracks your config changes in the current profile.

Comment: Are you trying to 1. Specifically affect the entire VS Code configuration regardless of the Workspace or 2. Affect only a specific Workspace?

Comment: @oxou I am trying to affect all workspaces that have a specific profile

Answer (score 2):

It looked scary, but I could simply uninstall the Python Linting extension when I am in a TypeScript profile and when I later open a project with the Python profile, the extension would still be installed for that project.